# In-App Purchase Purchase Request not display purchase window

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I added an Application in Google Play Market. After that i added two products and publish them. After that i purchased some products with my test account. But 2 Days later when i tried to purchase a product. Google play server not gives me any Error and also not shows Purchase window.

Comment: Have you tried in different Browsers to imitate the Same??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was created test account which you used to purchase the product. After several purchases the Google play blocks that account for some time for purchases. I faced that problem already, and I did R&D on that. Finaly we implemented a solution i.e **create another test account and do purchase using it, as old account get blocked for purchase** . After some days you can try with previous account, then it will work fine.